# Still want to use "ptm" in XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I'm using XeLaTeX typesetting Chinese fonts in my document. (So XeLaTeX is the only suitable way for me to do my stuff.) I want to use the LaTex original `ptm` font to typeset all English text.

I know there is a simple way to use `Times`-related fonts in XeLaTeX, like `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}`. But in this way, the ligature doesn't work, even if using:

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
```

And anyhow, I still want to use the original `ptm` font, not `Times New Roman`. There're still some essential designing difference if one look closer at it. I prefer `ptm`. So how can I use `ptm`?

I'd found

```
\DeclareFixedFont{\PTMtext}{OT1}{ptm}{m}{n}{12pt}
\PTMtext{blah blah}
```

works, but only affects in a little region, i.e. cannot work in `section` title or math inline mode such like `$a=0 \text{if needed}$`, in which 'if needed' is still in `lmr` style. And `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}` doesn't work too.

Comment: `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}`

Comment: Ligatures should work on a font that has them. You’d want `Ligatures={Common, TeX}` or for some fonts, Discretionary, Rare or Contextual ligatures. Selecting only `Ligatures=TeX` turns most ligatures off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing more than a visual comparison, showing that `ptm` is exactly the same as what you get with TeX Gyre Termes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\newfontfamily{\OTIMES}{Times New Roman}

\def\fn"#1/#2"{#1}%

\begin{document}

{\OTIMES abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzfifl \expandafter\fn\fontname\font}

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzfifl \expandafter\fn\fontname\font

{\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzfifl \fontname\font}

{\OTIMES ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ \expandafter\fn\fontname\font}

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ \expandafter\fn\fontname\font

{\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ \fontname\font}

\itshape

{\OTIMES abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzfifl \expandafter\fn\fontname\font}

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzfifl \expandafter\fn\fontname\font

{\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzfifl \fontname\font}

{\OTIMES ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ \expandafter\fn\fontname\font}

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ \expandafter\fn\fontname\font

{\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ \fontname\font}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can also see, also the italic font in TeX Gyre Termes matches `ptm`, although there are small differences in kerning.

Comment: There is another advantage, which is the matching `TeX Gyre Termes Math`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. By the way, what is the benefit of using `TeX Gyre Termes Math`? How does it compare to `MTPro2`?

Comment: @Eric MTPro2 has tons of bells and whistles, but is not a Unicode math font

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to downvote the answer because the result is different.Certainly the it looks similar but that is because we are seeing only the upright style. If we add to the code the italic shape, we will see some differences, specially in the z `glyph`.

Comment: @Dog_69 The OP wants the same as `ptm` and the italic z is the same in TeX Gyre Termes as in `ptm`. It is different in Times New Roman. Please, read the question more carefully. It is true that there are tiny differences in *kerning* between Termes and `ptm`, which is quite bad in that respect.

Comment: @egreg You are right. I forgot that `ptm` also has the same italic z. I apologize for the inconvenience. Anyway, this gives me an idea for a question.

Comment: @Dog_69 I edited my answer to add the comparison for italic.

Comment: @egreg: And I gave you a point for y +1 for your fantastic answer.

Comment: Concerning your “ptm is exactly the same as what you get with TeX Gyre Termes”: “exactly” is way wrong or at least not what your example shows us. For an excerpt from your output at magnification 45.4x see https://i.ibb.co/cwYNZm7/PRS.png for the differences in the capital P, R, and S; I drew red circles around the places to be paid attention to. Also the right foot of the upper R (in Times New Roman) is about 9% longer than the right foot of the lower R (in TeX Gyre Termes), whereas for the left foot or the R, the ratio is only 2 %.

Answer (score 2):

Define an own fontface. If you are using one of the KOMA-Script classes
you can define the headers in an easy way to use Times.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setmainfont{what ever you want}
\newfontface\Times{Times New Roman MT Std}% I have only this otf version
\begin{document}
Latin Modern

{\Times $a=0 \text{ if needed}$}

\section{LatinModern}
\subsection{\Times Times New Roman} 
foo \Times foo
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want to use `ptm`, not Times New Roman. And is there a way to set the `ptm` font as default style? Not always puts a `\command{}` arounding texts.

Comment: Then use the `TeX Gyre Termes` as main font end everything will be fine